# Парсинг рабочей защищенной сети

Tags: python, парсер

Начал изучать Python и столкнулся с первыми трудностями, имеется CRM Redmine, через которую поступают обращения от пользователей, к этой сети я подключаюсь через Cisco.
Готовый код парсинга у меня уже есть, я создал массив, в который должны поступать данные с Redmine.
При запуске ошибок в коде нет, но массив в который программа должна была "положить" значения пустой.
Код прилагаю.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

HOST = 'http://redmine.easuz.mosreg.ru/'
URL = 'http://redmine.easuz.mosreg.ru/projects/picsupport/issues?page=1&query_id=263'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.86 YaBrowser/20.8.0.894 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params =''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='hascontextmenu')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(

            {
                'subject': item.find('td', class_='subject').get_text(),
                'link_zayav': item.find('td', class_='subject').find('a').get('href')
            }
        )
    return cards

html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

Comment: Браузер пишет: `Хмм. Нам не удаётся найти этот сайт.` :) Раз список пустой, значит `items` тоже пустой, а это значит, что либо у вас неправильные поисковые атрибуты указаны, либо нет в ответе нужных тегов. Сохраните в файл ответ и проверьте наличие `class` с `hascontextmenu`. Если его нет, то скорее всего тут замешан `javascript`, например подгрузкой данных

Answer (score 0):

У Redmine есть [классное апи](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/rest_api). Не нужно парсить - просто загружай все заявки

```
GET  /issues.json

{ "issues":[...], "total_count":2595, "limit":25, "offset":0 }
```

Также возможно надо прописать redmine.easuz.mosreg.ru в hosts